# JavaScript code within component.html in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

so I have this javascript code that I want to add into my somename.component.html file in Angular 6 but I know it doesn't work that way, can't create a file and just put the code there cause when I tried it didn't work

```
<script>

  /**
   * Push left instantiation and action.
   */
   var pushLeft = new Menu({
     wrapper: '#o-wrapper',
     type: 'push-left',
     menuOpenerClass: '.c-button',
     maskId: '#c-mask'
   });

   var pushLeftBtn = document.querySelector('#c-button--push-left');

   pushLeftBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault;
     pushLeft.open();
   });

   /**
    * Slide right instantiation and action.
    */
    var slideRight = new Menu({
      wrapper: '#o-wrapper',
      type: 'slide-right',
      menuOpenerClass: '.c-button',
      maskId: '#c-mask'
    });

    var slideRightBtn = document.querySelector('#c-button--slide-right');

    slideRightBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault;
      slideRight.open();
    });


    /**
    * Slide top instantiation and action.
    */
    var slideTop = new Menu({
      wrapper: '#o-wrapper',
      type: 'slide-top',
      menuOpenerClass: '.c-button',
      maskId: '#c-mask'
    });

    var slideTopBtn = document.querySelector('#c-button--slide-top');

    slideTopBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault;
      slideTop.open();
    });
```

it's starting to piss me off trying to figure it out, cause this is my second Angular project so I'm still not familiar with everything.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe you can try to put this code inside your component "ts" file inside one of the life cycle hooks ngAfterViewInit. I don't know what Menu is so probably Typescript will complain. But far better is to achieve same behavior with the Angular way.

Comment: Menu is “an instance of a class” I can’t remeber if that’s how it’s said, hahahaha I apologize, from the main.js file that you provide different parameters based on what button was clicked. And yeah it did complain, mmmh